# How do I disable CKEditor from adding "cke:" to the beginning of object tags?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm trying to create a simple plugin for CKEditor that pastes a snippet of code into the editor. I have tried adding exceptions to the content filter, and even disabling the content filter entirely using `config.allowedContent = true;`
In my `config.js` file.

When the `<object></object>` tag is first pasted into the editor it works fine, but when the user either switches to "source" mode and back to WYSIWYG mode I find that the `<object>` tag is now turned into a `<cke:object></cke:object>` tag which causes it to disappear from WYSIWYG mode.

How can I disable this feature?

I admit I dont fully understand the source code, but I dug around and the culprit(s) seem to be the file:

```
/ckeditor/core/filter.js
```

between lines 1463 and 1533

and also in:

```
/ckeditor/core/htmldataprocessor.js
```

starting on line 788.

Note: I am using CKEditor 4.5.6

They both contain references to the `cke:` and regex to append/remove that `cke:`prefix.

I tried looking here on Stack Overflow, the documentation, and even [submitted a ticket](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/13804) months ago but I haven't been able to find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you do not have a feature which will handle this `<object>` tag. For example if you enable Flash plugin and insert a Flash object it will be transformed to a placeholder (check [this code](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/flash/plugin.js#L92-L121)). Because of security there can not be `<object>` tag inside the editable area, it needs to be handled by a plugin and transformed into a placeholder or a widget.

Comment: Thanks Piotr! Unfotunately, I have more questions now.  
  
Can you elaborate more on what you mean by security? Is it the browsers security or the editors security? It seems like object tags are able to work perfectly fine in the editor before they are converted to `cke:object` tags. [Here is a screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/bIb4tel.png).  
  
Also, why does the editor show the object tag when it is first inserted with `editor.insertElement( embedTag );`  
  
Can you recommend instructions/documentation on integrating with the fakeObjects plugin like the flash plugin does?

Comment: The point is `<object>` should not be a part of the editable area. There is no way it can be editable like text or paragraph. However, it can be a non-editable element inside the editor, with some editable parts. This is what CKEditor call widget, here is a tutorial how to create it: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/widget_sdk_intro

Comment: Thanks Piotr! After reading and going through the widget documentation, I was able to get my plugin implemented using the widget framework. Thanks!